# Subir imagenes con PHP a carpeta

Tags: php, html

en internet consegui este codigo para subir imagenes

```
<?  
if($_POST){ 
// Creamos la cadena aletoria 
$str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; 
$cad = ""; 
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++) { 
$cad .= substr($str,rand(0,62),1); 
} 
// Fin de la creacion de la cadena aletoria 
$tamano = $_FILES [ 'file' ][ 'size' ]; // Leemos el tamaño del fichero 
$tamaño_max="50000000000"; // Tamaño maximo permitido 
if( $tamano < $tamaño_max){ // Comprovamos el tamaño  
$destino = 'uploaded' ; // Carpeta donde se guardata 
$sep=explode('image/',$_FILES["file"]["type"]); // Separamos image/ 
$tipo=$sep[1]; // Optenemos el tipo de imagen que es 
if($tipo == "gif" || $tipo == "pjpeg" || $tipo == "bmp"){ // Si el tipo de imagen a subir es el mismo de los permitidos, segimos. Puedes agregar mas tipos de imagen 
move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES [ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $destino . '/' .$cad.'.'.$tipo);  // Subimos el archivo 
include('post.html'); // Incluimos la plantilla 
} 
else echo "el tipo de archivo no es de los permitidos";// Si no es el tipo permitido lo desimos 
} 
else echo "El archivo supera el peso permitido.";// Si supera el tamaño de permitido lo desimos 
} 
?>
```

y este es el form.html

```html
<script>
function ver(image){
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img src='"+image+"'>" 
}
</script>
<form action="sube.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    Archivo: <input name="file" type="file"  onChange="ver(form.file.value)"> 
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload!">  
</form><br> <span id="image"></span>
```

La cuestion es que lo he probado en local y no me funciona nose porque, algo estoy haciendo mal ya que a todos en el foro dicen que les ha funcionado este codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulario en el Index.html o php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Elegir archivo:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "imagenes/"; //directorio en el que se subira
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);//se añade el directorio y el nombre del archivo
$uploadOk = 1;//se añade un valor determinado en 1
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Comprueba si el archivo de imagen es una imagen real o una imagen falsa
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {//detecta el boton
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {//si es falso es una imagen y si no lanza error
        echo "Archivo es una imagen- " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "El archivo no es una imagen";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Comprobar si el archivo ya existe
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "El archivo ya existe";
    $uploadOk = 0;//si existe lanza un valor en 0
}
// Comprueba el peso
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Perdon pero el archivo es muy pesado";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Permitir ciertos formatos de archivo
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Perdon solo, JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF Estan soportados";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
//Comprueba si $ uploadOk se establece en 0 por un error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Perdon, pero el archivo no se subio";
// si todo está bien, intenta subir el archivo
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " Se subio correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "Error al cargar el archivo";
    }
}
?>
```

Este codigo lo saque de https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_file_upload.asp

Comment: Si yo quisiera cambiar el nombre del archivo en donde podría poner mi variable, en el formulario pondría un campo $nuevonombredeimagen y en que parte del PHP al recibir los archivos debería colocar esta variable para que sea guardada con ese nombre?

Answer (score 1):

Si quisieras cambiar el nombre del archivo que el cliente subió al servidor o que tú mismo subiste podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```js
$target_dir = "../image/"; //directorio en el que se subira
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);//se añade el directorio y el nombre del archivo
$uploadOk = 1;//se añade un valor determinado en 1
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$name_File= basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);//Tomamos el nombre del archivo.
$encriptar2=md5(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])).".".$imageFileType;/*En este caso lo encripté con md5, si quisiseras ponerle un nombre a tu elección puedes simplemente cambiar la variable y poner $encriptar="nombre a tú elección"*/
$resultado=$encriptar .".".$imageFileType;/*concatenamos el nuevo nombre con la extensión del archivo que está tomado mediante $imageFileType*/



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
  rename("../image/$name_File","../image/$encriptar2");//cambiamos el nombre del archivo mediante rename()
    echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " Se subio correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Error al cargar el archivo";
}
}
```